# How to set cron job run every hour and stop run 6 pm

Tags: cpanel

Set Cron job Cpanel

> Ex. start 9 am. - 6 pm.

How can I do that?Can anyone help me?

Comment: You failed to mention the tools that you are aiming to do this with. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below values will start your cron job every hour from 9 AM to 6 PM.
**0 9-18 * * ***

It could be said that this job would run “At minute 0 past every hour from 9 through 18.”

Here, 0 is the minute, 9-18 represents 9 AM to 6PM (24hr format), next three * represents any date, month and day respectively.

Say, If you want to run this cron job only on Monday to Friday, from 9AM to 6PM you can try this:
**0 9-18 * * 1-5**

For above values, It could be said that the set cron job would run “At minute 0 past every hour from 9 through 18 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.”

You can read this link to know how to set these values for a cron job in Cpanel [here](https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-configure-a-cron-job/)

Comment: Hope this helps.